# Result calculation from a fix date and an expected future event

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, series

I have a serious problem to understand how this pandas/numpy dataframe/series works in details.

The problem which I am trying to solve is that I have two indicators - MACD and AROON.

If the MACD is above zero (time t0), the AROON should be twice by 100 (t0, t1, t2, etc), without that MACD is going below zero (t1, t2, etc). If a counter is two and the MACD was continuously above zero a buy signal should be generated.

```
def find_buy_signal(xDate, xMacd, xAroon):
    for n in range(0, len(xDate)):
        if (xMacd.shift(n).macd > 0)[n]:
            for m in range(n, len(xDate)):
                buy_signal_counter = 0
                if (xMacd.shift(m).macd > 0):
                    if (xAroon.shift(m).up == 100):
                        buy_signal_counter += 1
                        if buy_signal_counter == 2:
                            return True
                else:
                    return False
         else:
             return False   

data = read_data()
xMacd = macd(data, 10, 15, 1)    
xAroon = aroon(data, 12)
buy = find_buy_date(xMacd.index, xMacd, xAroon)
print(buy) # The result is False but should be a series
```

Even if I know the pseudo code I'm able to bring the two timeframes together.

Here are some example data for MACD:

```
                    fast  hist       macd     signal          slow
Date                                                              
2018-04-08  12358.294033   0.0 -96.857954 -96.857954  12455.151987  
2018-04-15  12391.422390   0.0 -74.398098 -74.398098  12465.820488
2018-04-22  12425.867432   0.0 -54.334260 -54.334260  12480.201692
2018-04-29  12497.455100   0.0 -25.171331 -25.171331  12522.626432 
2018-05-04  12556.026829   0.0  -3.721250  -3.721250  12559.748079
```

Here some sample data with Aroon:

```
             down          up
Date  
2018-04-08  83.333333    8.333333
2018-04-15  75.000000    0.000000
2018-04-22  66.666667    0.000000
2018-04-29  58.333333  100.000000
```

I'm aware that I can merge the two dataframes into one dataframe.

Here the expected result for a signal and not:

```
            macd        up
 Date
 t0      macd > 0   100.00 (counter == 1)
 t1      macd > 0    96.00
 t2      macd > 0   100.00 (counter == 2) signal

            macd        up
 Date
 t0      macd > 0   100.00 (counter == 1)
 t1      macd > 0    96.00
 t2      macd < 0   100.00 (counter == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which is not what I was originally asking. The two dataframes are concatenated and named as concat. With

```
concat[(concat.macd > 0) & (concat.shift(-1).macd > 0) & (concat.up == 100) & (concat.shift(-1).up == 100)]
```

at least I was able to find the entries where the up value is twice 100. Maybe I will find the correct solution in the future.